# why is my JSON array output repeated 3 times?

Tags: php, json

I'm beginner to the JSON with PHP if you can please help me. the code repeat the same output in 3 times. I include the require codes here. The code details are given below. 
../Controller/controller.php has the MySQL code to retrieve data from database

donnerdata.js:

```
    function member_note(){
       var tableData;
    $.post("../Controller/controller.php", {loading_donnerdata: 'table'}, function(e) {
        if (e === undefined || e.length === 0 || e === null) {
            tableData = 'noData';
            $('#orders-datatable').html('').append(tableData);
        } else {
            $.each(e, function() {
               tableData += '<div class="row comment">';
               tableData += '<div class="col-sm-10">';
               tableData += '<div class="message clearfix">';
               tableData += '<div class="note">';
               tableData += '<p>';
               tableData += 'something';
               tableData += '</p>';
               tableData += '</div>';
               tableData += '</div>';
               tableData += '</div>';
            });
            //Load Json Data to Table
            $('#orders-datatable').html('').append(tableData);        

        }
    }, "json");
}
```

viewStudent.php:

```
    <div class="comments">      
       <div class="" id="orders-datatable">                   
    <?php require_once '../../Common/all_js_links.php'; ?>
    <script src="js/donnerdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {     
                member_note();
            });
        });

    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove this  $(function() {    from viewStudent.php and try

Comment: The element is emptied on each function call, so the only reasonable exaplanation is that the server is outputting the same three times, and you're showing us the wrong code ?

Comment: @adeneo that would imply that the server is responding multiple times on seperate requests. I think what is happening here is that $(document).ready() and $(function() {}) are synonymous. Meaning that the member_note is called twice. First step would be to remove the inner $(function() {}) and just call member_note() inside the $(document).ready() callback.

Comment: @adeneo, no that is my original code . there no any thing to pass as parameters there fore I leave it empty

Comment: @SimonH<script src="js/donnerdata.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // $(document).ready(function() {
     $(function() {
                    
                    member_note();

                });

  //  });

        </script>

Comment: @SimonH  it is not work.    <script type="text/javascript">
                                                          $(document).ready(function() {
                                                            member_note();
                                                             });
                                                             </script>

Comment: Are there any console errors, you will have to be more specific on what is not working.

Comment: @SimonH - you can nest jQuery DOM ready handlers as many times as you want, it still wont call the code inside more than once.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should :).

Comment: What I meant is that the only way you'd get the data thrice, is if the server outputs JSON with the same data repeated three times. Not three requests, **one** request, with JSON data repeated, otherwise it wouldn't repeat three times, as the code empties the elements with `html("")` on each function call. You need to post the serverside code.

Comment: @SimonH there are no any console errors

Comment: @SimonH - That's correct, one shouldn't, but it's not an issue either, and would never cause this.

Comment: Could you check what the POST request returns in your browser inspector Network tab? If you paste that it would be easier to help you. Or do `console.log(e)` in the callback and paste the output.

Comment: @user3732708 can you see a XHR call being made when using Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: @adeneo, i didn't get you,

Comment: The only way you'd see the same data repeated three times, is if the server sends the same data repeated three times.

Comment: @adeneo, then what can I do for solve this

Comment: Start by posting the data you get in the ajax request, or the serverside code that generates that data

Comment: I have solve the problem it affect the  $.post("../Controller/controller.php", {loading_donnerdata: 'table'}, function(e) { code because in the controller.php it call the sql function wich have 3 output it affect the program. Any way thank u very much to yours contribution

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your doubly-nested callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    member_note();
});
```

Comment: no it isn't work, when i edit code like that, it will disappear the output